# unable to extract range of columns from file using awk

Tags: awk

My input file has several lines which are each of length of 20.The length of the line is always fixed and I need to extract the first 5 values from each line in the input.txt file.

I have the follow code which I tried but I am not sure why the output.txt is always empty. I am taking the substring from column 1 to column 5, am I missing something is my code logic?

My input file: input.txt

```
0290This is the firm
12 I need to run the
02930290Time is vals
```

Sample output.txt:

```
0290T
12 I 
02930
```

My code as of now:

```
awk '{val=substr($0,1,5)} {print $val}' input.txt > output.txt
```

May someone help me find the code issue?

Comment: Use `{print val}`, not ``{print $val}``. Or just `awk '{print substr($0,1,5)}'  input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: For this trivial case, just use `cut -c 1-5`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for solving the issue. :) The $ was the issue.